# Google Map Overlay File Retrieval and Processing

Tags: google-maps, dropbox

I have an issue with the addition of a KML file to a google map.

When myURL is set to 'http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ggeoxml/cta.kml' as shown in the following code snippet, the map plus overlay displays as expected. The overlay file is taken from an example shared by Google.

When myURL is set to 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/hq09lfaya2cmu87/test.kml', Google returns an error saying that the document is invalid (status returned is INVALID_DOCUMENT) even though the content of each files is indentical.

```
       // var myURL = 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/hq09lfaya2cmu87/test.kml';

       var myURL = 'http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ggeoxml/cta.kml';

       var myLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
          url: myURL
       });

       google.maps.event.addListener(myLayer,'status_changed',function(){
       if (myLayer.getStatus() != 'OK') {
          alert('Google Maps could not load the layer: ' + myURL + ' Status returned is: ' + myLayer.getStatus());
        };
      });

     myLayer.setMap(map);
```

I suspect that the issue is to do with the use of HTTPS. Any advice on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is caused by the file download dialogue which is activated by default. Suppressing the file download dialogue through the use of the dl parameter solves the problem e.g.

var myURL = 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/hq09lfaya2cmu87/test.kml?dl=1'

working snippet:

```js
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(49.496675, -102.65625);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng
  }

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  var myURL = 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/hq09lfaya2cmu87/test.kml?dl=1';

  var myLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: myURL
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(myLayer, 'status_changed', function() {
    if (myLayer.getStatus() != 'OK') {
      alert('Google Maps could not load the layer: ' + myURL + ' Status returned is: ' + myLayer.getStatus());
    };
  });

  myLayer.setMap(map);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html, body, #map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I try to download your KML on dropbox, I get a login dialog, If I do the same to Google's file, I get the file.  Google doesn't have your dropbox credentials, the file *must* be ***publicly*** accessible.

Comment: In my dropbox, the permission settings is set such that "Anyone with the link" as opposed to "Only people with the password". So the file should be publicly accessible?

Comment: I think you meant that you get a download dialogue and that this is the issue as opposed to the file not being publicly available because it is. I will investigate this and report back.

Comment: It isn't publicly available (by the definition of the Google Maps Javascript API v3) if credentials are required, as the Google Maps server which will need access, won't be able to provide them.

Comment: The file download dialogue was suppressed by setting the dl parameter to 1 e.g. var myURL = 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/hq09lfaya2cmu87/test.kml?dl=1'  and the problem was solved. Thanks for your help in highlighting that a dialogue was causing the problem.